# check the file before downloading the file using php

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to check the file before downloading the file, 
i have controller Download and function download_file

here is my code :
i tired this code and i always get no

```
public function download_file($namafile,$nofile)
        {
    $filecek =(site_url()."/uploads/file/".$namafile);
        $data = file_get_contents(site_url().'/uploads/file/'.$namafile);

    echo "$filecek";

    if (!file_exists($filecek)) {
      echo "no";
    }else {
force_download($namafile,$data);
      echo "yes";
    }

        }
    }
```

and this is link for download

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>download/<?php echo $getFiles['file']; ?>/<?php echo $getFiles['nofile']; ?>"><i class="icon-download"></i> <?php echo $getFiles['kategori']; ?></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`site_url()` won't work that way because you always get the Website Url ...

`file_exists()` however checks whether a directory or file exists on your server or not - so you need an absolute position..

There is a `CONSTANT` called `FCPATH` which you can use - it points to the directory where your `index.php` resides.

So basically you can try the following

```
public function download_file($namafile,$nofile)
{
    $filecek = FCPATH."uploads/file/".$namafile;

    echo "$filecek";

    if (!file_exists($filecek)) 
    {
        echo "no";
    }
    else 
    {
        force_download($namafile, NULL);
        echo "yes";
    }
}
```

the only condition here is - that `uploads/file/` exists within your `FCPATH`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of `$filecek`?

IMO `$filecek =(site_url()."/uploads/file/".$namafile);` should be changed to `$filecek =(base_url()."/uploads/file/".$namafile);` because

```
echo base_url(); //http://example.com/website
echo site_url(); //http://example.com/website/index.php
```

For accessing resources `base_url()` is acceptable as you can't get a file in `http://example.com/website/index.php/file.ext`