# how to insert logo into excel downloaded file php

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

I want to insert a logo image into excel report file on click.

My code look like this->

```
$image= base_url('assets/images/mjobs_logo.png'); 
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();   
$objDrawing->setName('Customer Signature');       
$objDrawing->setDescription('Customer Signature');       
$objDrawing->setPath($image);
$objDrawing->setOffsetX(25);                      
$objDrawing->setOffsetY(10);                     
$objDrawing->setCoordinates($column.$cell);       
$objDrawing->setWidth(32);                 
$objDrawing->setHeight(32); 
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
```

But with using with above code i am getting this type of error.

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: PHPExcel_Exception

Message: File http://url/assets/images/mjobs_logo.png not found!

Filename: /home/company/application/libraries/PHPExcel/Worksheet/Drawing.php

Line Number: 111
```

Comment: `base_url()`, `site_url()` won't work here - use `FCPATH` i explained that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50426788/check-the-file-before-downloading-the-file-using-php/50427321#50427321

Answer (score 0):

For the image to be visible in the Excel file, you shall have to give the complete URL like

```
http://yourwebsite.com/assets/images/mjobs_logo.png
```

And the computer that is used to open the Excel file will have to have connectivity to that website.

Answer (score 0):

> You may try this code to insert a logo in your PDF structure

```
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
                $objDrawing->setName('Logo');
                $objDrawing->setDescription('Logo');
                $logo = base_url() . 'images/logo.png'; // Provide path to your logo file
                $objDrawing->setPath($pr_file);
                $objDrawing->setOffsetX(8);    // setOffsetX works properly
                $objDrawing->setOffsetY(300);  //setOffsetY has no effect
                $objDrawing->setCoordinates('B1');
                $objDrawing->setHeight(75); // logo height
                $objDrawing->setWorksheet($this->excel->getActiveSheet());
```